# How can I define a function that takes as a parameter a pointer value of any kind?

Tags: c++, pointers, assignment-operator

I'm implementing for practice a smart pointer class.

I already defined an assignment operator overload that takes another instance of the same class. Now I want to define an overload of this operator, that takes any pointer. So I should be able to do stuff like `smartPointer = &someObject;` or `smartPointer = NULL;`, etc.

How can I go about doing that? Should I pass in a `void*`? Something else?

As a more general question (and I know this is rarely desired): what kind of parameter tells the compiler that any pointer can be passed in?

Comment: In practice, you probably don't want this.  Because it would mean you could easily do `smartPointer1 = rawPointer; smartPointer2 = rawPointer;` - now, who deletes the memory?

Comment: You may use template method: `template <typename T> MySmartPointer& MySmartPointer::operator =(T* p);`

Comment: @Jarod42 I thought about that, but I think this isn't what I want because this means that if the client does `smart_pointer = raw_pointer`, the parameter passed in would be a pointer to the pointer. Am I wrong?

Comment: @AvivCohn: to get a pointer to the pointer, client would use `smart_pointer = &raw_pointer`.

Comment: @Jarod42 Wait a minute: does `(T* p)` mean "`T` must be a pointer type"?

Comment: @AvivCohn: `T*` must be a pointer type, `T` may or may not be a pointer type.

Comment: @Jarod42 So that means that if `T` *is* a pointer type, it's passed by value - as it is - into the function. But what happens if `T` isn't a pointer type?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62708/discussion-between-jarod42-and-aviv-cohn).

Answer (score 1):

You can use a template function to make your object allow any pointer to be assigned to it.

```
template<typename T>
void operator=(T* obj)
{
    //Your code here
}
```

However, its not a smart pointer if you could assign it any raw pointers as it could be assigned to more than one smart pointer object and then there would be a problem while deleting the pointer.

Answer (score 1):

Following may help:

```
class MySharedPointer
{
public:

    template <typename T>
    MySharedPointer& operator = (T* p)
    {
        ptr.reset(p, [](void* p) { delete static_cast<T*>(p); });
        return *this;
    }

    // nullptr is not a pointer, so it should have its own overload.
    MySharedPointer& operator = (std::nullptr_t) {
        ptr.reset();
        return *this;
    }

private:
    std::shared_ptr<void> ptr;
};
```

[Live example](https://ideone.com/ebaUuv)